# Xamarin.Forms: Press back button from code

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Is there a way in Xamarin.Forms to press the back button from code? I tried to call OnBackButtonPressed and SendBackButtonPressed but this does not work. The OnBackButtonPressed Event is called but the back action does not perform.

Call OnBackButtonPressed:

```
if (_currentQuestionnaireGroup != null)
   await RefreshDataAsync();
else
{
   App.QuestionnaireOverviewPage.IsDirty = true;
   this.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

Event:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if (_questionnaireHandler != null)
        App.QuestionnaireOverviewPage.IsDirty = true;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Sorry for the poor english

In your Event, change `return true;` for `return base.OnBackButtonPressed();`.

When you return true, the action 'back' is canceled at device.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Your solution works when i press the hardware backbutton on android. But i have a custom back button. When i click this custom button and just call OnBackButtonPressed, the back action is not performed. Both hit the OnBackButtonPressed - Event but only the hardware back button performs the real back action.

Comment: I usted use a Navigation.PopAsync() to do this, If I undertood correctly. Can you post your whole code? I'll try simulate your scenario here and get the trick.

Comment: Yes to use Navigation.PopAsync() is the right way and solves the problem. I have some experience in native android development and there you can just call finish() or onBackPressed() to close the current Page. In Xamarin.Forms you have to call Navigation.PopAsync().